# Unable to save password for xtightvnc viewer

Tags: vnc

I am accessing display of one rpi from another rpi using vnc. Everything is working fine but i want to autostart xtightvnc viewer on boot. But I don't know how to enter password? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got a solution. I copied passwd file from the rpi with vncserver to rpi with client. Then i called in client, the following command

```
xtightvncviewer 192.168.0.54:1 -passwd /home/pi/.vnc/passwd
```